# How can I handle the change event with React-Hook-Form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onchange, react-hook-form

I am trying to figure out onChange event using react hook form controller for materialui select but I cannot figure out how to trigger the event when select changes to call handleChange event. I have created a sandbox to replicate where I also have separate issue of `Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode` which I can't get my head around how to use the createRef to stop this but the main problem is onChange event as I need to render different further TextFields based off the Select-value.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-select-onchange-uiic6

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
    <Grid item>
      <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Folder Name</InputLabel>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="folderSelect"
          onChange={handleChange}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({onChange, value, onBlur, name}) => (
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              onChange={onChange}
              value={value ? value : ''}
              name={name}>
              <MenuItem value="Invoices" key="Invoices">
                Invoices
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Statements" key="Statements">
                Statements
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Credits" key="Credits">
                Credits
              </MenuItem>
            </Select>
          )}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="First Name"
        name="firstName"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        inputRef={register({required: true})}
      />
    </Grid>
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </Grid>
</form>;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `onChange` method for `Controller` as you defined in your code. So you can remove it this:

```
<Controller
                    control={control}
                    name="folderSelect"
                    onChange={() => console.log("hellow")} <- this one not required
                    defaultValue=""
```

What I understand for your question you want to trigger `handleChange` as soon as `select` value updated. For this you can do this:

```
 <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          onChange(e)
                          handleChange(e) <- call handleChange
                        }}
                        value={value ? value : ""}
                        name={name}
                      >
```

Here is code and demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-select-onchange-forked-eqb20?file=/src/App.js:1533-1907

Answer (score 0):

So if you wants to trigger handleChange on select's onChange then simply change `onChange={onChange}` to `onChange={() => handleChange()}`.

**Note:** If you wants to remove findDom deprecated warning then simply remove `React.StrictMode` tag from `ReactDOM.render` in `index.js`

Comment: thanks for input i know i can remove strictmode but i assumed its best not to that its there for a reason? tried using useRef createRef but to be honest it was just chancing it would work dont really understnad it,